# Laravel 8: Problem creating and using a a new Permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have a Laravel 8 Project on my Local Windows PC. I uploaded the project to my shared web hosting on Dreamhost via zip file and copying the entire database to remote host. (I am unable to use Composer and php artisan commands on the remote server) I am using Spatie Roles & Permissions in my project.

Later I had to add a new permission 'holiday_vacation' in my project. I created the new permission using artisan commands on my local system I believe that when a new permission is created, it adds a new record in the `permissions` table and a when a user is given access to a specific permission, a record is added to the `model_has_permissions` table. I believe that no other table is changed during this process. The newly created 'holiday_vacation' permission works fine on my local system.

However, after I manually updated the remote tables (permissions and model_has_permissions), the remote system is unable to find the new permission (holiday_vacation). The following commands in a controller display error message, "There is no permission named `holiday_vacation` for guard `web`."

```
if(auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('holiday_vacation') )
{
    dd("Has access");
}
```

I am absolutely sure that the permissions table has the `holiday_vacation` permission as I copied the permissions and model_has_permissions tables from the local database to the remote one.

Google search on this issue talks about clearing permission cache (e.g. php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache then php artisan cache:clear). Unfortunately, I can't execute php artisan commands on my shared hosting.

Can someone offer a workaround, please?

Comment: What cache driver are you using? (Also, time to ditch shared hosting.)

Comment: You can try removing cache by executing `app()[Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BABAK ASHRAFI's comment did the trick, except that the command needed to be modified slightly. (Ref:  https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/cache)

```
app()->make(\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class)->forgetCachedPermissions();
```

Comment: if it solved your problem, mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: FYI: If the class is bound by the container then @babak-ashrafi 's solution should work as well.